# phpMyAdmin: default database ignored after FROM

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, phpmyadmin

This is a very annoying anomaly that happens only in phpMyAdmin, not through php's mysqli nor mysql command line.

I have two databases, `foo` and `bar`.
`foo.bananaTable.monkeyId` is a foreign key for `bar.monkey.id`

So, regardless of where you execute it, the SQL below will work fine, as-is:

```
SELECT bananaTable.ripeness as 'ripeness'
FROM bar.monkey as monkey
JOIN foo.bananaTable as bananaTable ON bananaTable.monkeyId = monkey.id
```

Now, if you navigate to the `foo` database in phpMyAdmin, it effectively uses `foo` as your default database if you don't explicitly name one in your SQL.  Therefore, the below SQL (leaving out the `foo` db scope in the JOIN) *should* work....

```
SELECT bananaTable.ripeness as 'ripeness'
FROM bar.monkey as monkey
JOIN bananaTable as bananaTable ON bananaTable.monkeyId = monkey.id
```

And it DOES work in php mysqli AND in mysql command line.  But it does NOT work in phpMyAdmin  You get an error saying `#1146 Table "bar.bananaTable" doesn't exist`.

This is telling me that FROM is totally hijacking my default database in phpMyAdmin.  In fact, if you edit this and run it again, you'll notice that it's actually moved you over to the `bar` database... WTF?

Ok, so I tried one more thing:

```
USE foo;
SELECT bananaTable.ripeness as 'ripeness'
FROM bar.monkey as monkey
JOIN bananaTable as bananaTable ON bananaTable.monkeyId = monkey.id
```

...to try and force it.  STILL no workey!

Has anyone seen this?  Is this just an artifact of phpMyAdmin trying to be too smart?  Is there a config that is centered around this?  Or is this some weirdness in MySql that I need to watch out for?  I'm all for explicit db naming, but for security reasons, we're specifying a default from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The phpMyAdmin version isn't specified, but it does not appear to be version related.  The following test shows the same behavior in the latest version of phpMyAdmin. Looks like a bug to me.

```sql
-- http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config
-- phpMyAdmin Demo Server: Currently running Git revision RELEASE_4_3_0RC2-1597-g6111104

-- Create table in test database

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bar (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  fooID int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO bar (id, name, fooID) VALUES
(1, 'first', 1),
(2, 'second', 2);

ALTER TABLE bar
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

-- Create table in world database

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `val1` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `foo` (`id`, `val1`) VALUES
(1, 10),
(2, 15);

ALTER TABLE `foo`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

-- from world database, where table foo resides

-- this query shows world as the default/selected database, as expected.

SELECT DATABASE();

-- this query should work from world, but fails with #1146 - Table 'test.foo' doesn't exist 

SELECT b.*, f.val1 
FROM test.bar AS b 
LEFT JOIN foo AS f ON f.id = b.fooID
WHERE 1;

-- this query succeeds with an explicit world.foo, but it shouldn't be required

SELECT b.*, f.val1 
FROM test.bar AS b 
LEFT JOIN world.foo AS f ON f.id = b.fooID
WHERE 1;
```